# Excel Timeseries Forecasting with Seasonality

Tags: excel, time-series, data-analysis, finance, forecasting

I am trying to create a forecast using a monthly timeseries data set of marketing expenses for a fictional company. The data looks something like this:

[image: Marketing Expenses Data Set]

Using linear regression to forecast future sales, I get the following result:

[image: Linear Regression]

My problem lies with the seasonality of the marketing expenses (higher in the summer months for instance). I would ideally like to calculate to forecasted values of future months including seasonality. I read somewhere about ARIMA forecasting, but am really searching for some best ideas on how to accomplish the task.

To be clear, I do not **JUST** want a chart and trendline, but the data to support it too.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: These two links [Basic Excel Business Analytics #56: Forecasting with Linear Regression: Trend & Seasonal Pattern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9LXjZfcgOo)    and [Excel Forecasting Seasonal Data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzlgKBkJJr0)

Comment: To do this properly you need enough historic data and you need to ensure you have cleaned your data properly (e.g. handling outliers, missing values.....etc...2016 has some inbuilt options e.g. interpolation)  - simply having the tools without knowing how to create a usable dataset is pointless. Also, you need to determine the periodicity of your time series (though the inbuilt 2016 will give an option to automatically detect this). The inbuilt Excel tool can output some measures to support the forecast such as MAE (measures of error essentially between forecasts against actuals).

Comment: ARIMA is more complicated as you need to start understanding autocorrelation (Interpreting ACF and PACF plots) and the like when determining which parameters to set your model at. I would go with Python or R for something like that though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily using Excel (2016) Forecast tool by first selecting your data, then clicking on:

Data -> Forecast Sheet -> Options -> Set Manually (under Seasonality)

You can also play with the options. Once you click on "Create", Excel will generate a graph, and a table with relevant data.

Alternatively, you can also create a binary variable for each season, and calculate a multiple regression for the Marketing expenses controlling for time, and each of the binary variables for the seasons but one (which is the reference group). You could either use excel analytical tool, or any other statistical software.

Comment: Should be mentioned that there is a `FORECAST.ETS` Excel function used. For ex. if expenses values are in `B2:B28`and the months in `A2:A28`and the first new month Jan 2014 is in `A29`, then `=FORECAST.ETS(A29,$B$2:$B$28,$A$2:$A$28,12,1)` can be used as formula too. The 12 states the saisonality of 12 months.